# Change the behavior of the bookmark star in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

is there any way for a Chrome Extension to change the behavior of the Google Chrome Bookmark Star Button?

What I want to do:

1. I want to change the icon of the star (both, the white and the filled yellow version)
2. When new star button is clicked, it should add a bookmark to Google Chrome just like the original way the button works, but display a custom form instead of Googles default form.

Is that possible? I have not found any way to alter "built-in" functionality in Google Chrome.

However, Google itself does exactly what I want with this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik

By now, I have only found a way to alter the "bookmarks" *page* itself (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override)

Any hints on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard way: install this google extension, go to $APP_PATH/google-chromeDefault/Extensions/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik and read the code :)

Comment: Ok, shame on me. It is really this easy:



"chrome_ui_overrides": {
      "bookmarks_ui": {
         "remove_bookmark_open_pages_shortcut": true,
         "remove_bookmark_shortcut": true,
         "remove_button": true
      }
   },

Comment: OK, it is obviously not that easy. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/ui_override states that chrome has to be started with --enable-override-bookmarks-ui=1 and it has to be a dev channel version. So, I guess they make it only available for their own product (Bookmark Manager)? ;)

Comment: @AlexGrund Please make that into an answer. Yes, it's a whitelisted, private API at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bookmark Manager App added this to its manifest:

```
  "chrome_ui_overrides" : {
    "bookmarks_ui": {
      "remove_button": "true",
      "remove_bookmark_shortcut": "true"
    }
  },
```

(as outlined here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/ui_override)

However, that seems to work only in Dev channel Chrome with `--enable-override-bookmarks-ui=1` start argument or for the Google Bookmark extension itself.